# libgomp missing: install c++ compiler in home directory?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, openmp, opensuse

I am working on a machine with

```
Linux version 2.6.16.46-0.12-smp (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 4.1.2 20070115 (prerelease) (SUSE Linux)) #1 SMP Thu May 17 14:00:09 UTC 2007
```

and I don't have root privileges. I was trying to compile a self-written program that needs OpenMP. However limgomp is not installed and thus compilation fails.

Is there a way to install my program, e.g. by somehow using a newer compiler in my home directory or something?

Thanks.

Comment: Linux is designed so that you cannot install packages without root access *for security reasons*. So, I doubt you will have success installing this package. You may find better help at http://superuser.com

Comment: @Alex W: He doesn't need to *install*, just compile and run.  He can do all that at ~ if he has the quota for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a compiler and sufficient space in writable directories, sure, you can just fetch the sources for missing packages and compile them there.

Installing programs from source usually consists of three steps:  configuring, building / compiling and installing (copying to target locations).  Read the README to find out what you have to change for configure, then usually just run `make` and install into your home directory or skip the install step altogether.

Add the path to the resulting executables to your PATH and you should be able to run your newly compiled programs.

Expect to spend several hours (or days) for reading documentation and waiting for compilation to finish (depends on how much you have to compile).  Or, maybe, look for another way to get things done.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to compile the dependencies yourself and put the libraries in your home folder somewhere, and then add their location to your PATH variable.

If you're doing this on a university computer system, you might consider sending an email to your friendly local network administrator and ask him to install them for you, I had to do the same thing at RIT to get them to install the openssl development libraries.

Comment: That's what I thought and did for boost and hdf5. The cmake binaries are also in my home folder and all of that works nicely. But for OpenMP you usually have to activate the compiler flag -fopenmp... My admin is sadly no big help so far, but that would be the best way to do it...